# Как найти самую короткую лексикографически минимальную палиндромную подстроку в строке?

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, олимпиада, палиндромы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм нахождения самой короткой лексикографически минимальной палиндромной подстроки в строке.

Например, в случае строки "aboobaa" программа должна вывести "aa", а не "oo", так как "aa" лексикографически меньше чем "oo" ("a" идет раньше в таблице ASCII чем "o").

> По условию задачи пустая строка и строка из одного символа не являются палиндромами.

Желательно, язык C++, так как нужно уложиться по времени в секунду. А длина строки достигает 200 000 символов.
Но можно и python.

Comment: Пустая строка - палиндромная. Любая строка из одного  символа - палиндромная.

Comment: Подумайте над вопросом: почему не надо искать кратчайшую палиндромную из десяти символов?

Comment: не знаю. пустая строка не является палиндромной в условиях задачи, и ответом задачи может быть минимум две буквы, например "aa".

Comment: Имеет смысл написать об этом в вопросе. Что ещё из условий опущено?

Comment: это все..........

Comment: т.е. нужно найти первые попавшиеся две буквы аа, правильно? или там еще цифры и др символы, предлагаю показать все задание, а не вытягивать условия.

Comment: @Oopss например, при вводе "abac" надо вывести "aba". при вводе "yandex" выводим -1, так как нет палиндромов-подстрок.
при вводе "abooba" выводим наикратчайшую палиндромную подстроку "oo". а в случае если у нас строка "ooaa" то выводим "aa" так как "a" идет раньше чем "o" в таблице ascii (алфавите ). все...

Answer (score 2):

> Алгоритм нахождения самой короткой палиндромной подстроки в строке.
> Ответом задачи может быть минимум две буквы.

Палиндромы могут быть четной длины и нечетной длины, палиндром четной длины больше двух содержит в себе палиндром длиной в два символа v**bb**v, палиндром нечетной длины больше трех символов, содержит в себе палиндром длиной в три символа s**dfd**s? значит задача сводится к поиску двух и трех символьных палиндромов т.е. самых коротких.

```py
import random

# Генерируем строку s для примера
c = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwvyxz'
s = ''.join([c[random.randint(0, 25)] for _ in range(200_000)])
# s - строка из 200_000 символов из c

# pol - список найденных палиндромов
# Если первый и второй символ равны инициализируем список
pol = [s[0] + s[1]] if s[0] == s[1] else  []
pol1 = []
for i, j, k in zip(s, s[1:], s[2:]):
    # Если первый и третий символы равны "fdf" заносим в список 
    if i == k:
        pol1.append(i + j + k)
    # Если второй и третий символы равны "fdd" заносим в список "dd" 
    if j == k:
        pol.append(j + k)
if pol:
   print(min(pol))
elif pol1:
   print(min(pol1))
else:
   print("Нет палиндромов")
```

Comment: Да, ошибка поправил спс

Comment: ОК, отлично....

Comment: Код, конечно, супер-неоптимальный. Зачем создавать список, когда можно хранить одну или две строки? А если мы нашли хотя бы одну строку длины 2, то можно уже не искать строки длины 3.